# How Can I Retrieve the Underlying List of an IEnumerable Without Creating a New List?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

When using `IEnumerable` I'm trying to avoid multiple enumerations. I know I can just use LINQ's `.ToList()` and be done with it, but that can be a lot of unnecessary list creation.  I'd like to:

1. check and see if the underlying type is a List, and if so return that instance, otherwise
2. `.ToList()` it and return the new List

My thought was to use something akin to:

```
public void Fee()
{
    var list = new List<string>(); // I want to retrieve this instance in Foo
    Foo(list);
}

public void Foo(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{  
    var list = enumerable as List<T> ?? enumerable.ToList();
    // do stuff with original list 
}
```

... but it appears from the documentation that the `as` operator just  performs a cast, which would create a new List rather than returning the underlying one, would it not?

If so, how can I retrieve the underlying list instead of creating a new one?

Comment: "*but it appears from the documentation that the as operator just performs a cast, which would create a new List rather than returning the underlying one, would it not?*" -- no, it would not

Comment: why not adjust foo to take the right type(s)?

Comment: You should probably cast that to `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead.

Comment: Why not use `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable` ? Or `IReadOnlyList<T>` ?

Comment: The whole purpose of `ToList` is to create a *new* list.  If you don't want a new list, don't call `ToList`.  There isn't an "underlying" list.

Comment: Note that `List<T>` is a generic type. `enumerable as List` won't compile. Did you mean `enumerable as List<string>`?

Comment: Your assumption is whrong. the `as`-cast does not create a new list, it just casts the existing if possible or returns null if not. So your question is simply not answerable, because it´s based upon a whrong assumption.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is `as List<Foo>` O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: `enumerable as List<string>` is compiled like  `enumerable is List<string> ? (List<string>)enumerable : null`

Comment: @RobertHarvey See my comment. A cast does not create a new object, thus no copying is involved.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: So it's O(1), then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, it just an operation which can be applied to both on collection types and non-collection types, so I'm not sure that using big-O notation makes sense. It's like asking whether instantiating a new object is O(n).

Comment: @canton7: No.  Lists have operations which are O(1), O(n), O(log n), etc.  Instantiating a new object is always O(1) unless it contains some sort of aggregate like, well, a list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But casting to a list is no of those "list-operations". Casting is just creating a new **reference** to the exact same object. The object itself isn´t touched at all.

Comment: "Instantiating a new object is always O(1) unless it contains some sort of aggregate like, well, a list." - no, instantiating a new object (which the `as` operator never does) can take an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of its aggregation. `var result = new PiCalculator(digits: 300000);` could take a very long time, for example... There's nothing special about `List<T>` here.

Comment: My point is that there's a lot of dancing around here about word definitions.  As the OP, all I'd really like to know is if this cast is going to work instantly or take the heat death of the universe to execute.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I repeat myself: a cast does not do **anything** except to create a new **reference**. I won´t expect this to take ages.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My point was, the `n` in `O(n)` is an argument of some sort. You've got an algorithm, and an input parameter `n` (or multiple input parameters). There's no input parameter with a cast - there's nothing you can change and see how long the algorithm takes in response. That does relate to the OP, because it says that the type of item being cast makes no significant difference to the time the cast will take - the two aren't connected (discounting very low-level implementation details)

Comment: @canton7: `ToList` doesn't take an argument either (unless you count the list as an argument, which I suppose it is).

Comment: @JonSkeet - yep, that's what I meant. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) does not create a new list. It only checks type and perform cast if type is compatible.

The code in the post is logically correct and matches how many LINQ methods are implemented (for example see source of [`Enumerable.Count`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b,references) which casts to `ICollection` to see if it can skip enumeration of items).

Note that it is important to cast to correct generic version of list or maybe one of its interfaces - `IList` would work if you must use non-generic version. Beware of the fact that `List<T>` is not co/contra-variant and type must match exactly unlike in case of [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) `IEnumerable<out T>` where you can cast parameter to `IEnumerable<TBase>` if `IEnumerable<TDerived>` passed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do this:

```
public void Fee()
{
    var list = new List<string>(); // I want to retrieve this instance in Foo
    Foo(list);
}

public void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    List<T> list = enumerable as List<T> ?? enumerable.ToList();
    // do stuff with original list 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant - but this isn't really an answer to the question.