# C# "fork" foreach IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

This is for C#: I have a very large `IEnumerable<T>` and I need to perform a check that would look like this on an `Array`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Size; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < Array.Size; j++)
    {
        Check(Array[j])
    }

    // Once the following operation is done, I don't care about n <= i elements
    DoStuff(Array[i]);
}
```

This is ~(n * n / 2) operations

The obvious solution is to use `ToArray()` and do what I just described, but that would mean copying to an array an doing the full loop once too many (n + n * n / 2).

I'm curious, is there a way to save the iteration index in order to "fork" the `foreach` loop. It would look like:

```
foreach (var elem in MyEnumerable)
{
    var forked = fork(MyEnumerable);
    
    foreach (var elem2 in forked)
    {
        Check(elem2);
    }
    
    DoStuff(elem);
}
```

I could also have some `counter` and replace my hypothetical `fork` function with `MyEnumerable.Skip(counter)`, but that again is not ideal since (I assume) in the back ground Skip is actually iterating so it would be (n * n) operations.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Do you know the concrete type of `MyEnumerable`? If it's not yet a reified set (one you can directly cast to an array or list), forking enumerables could be very costly. It could be an iterator that has to reperform some query to be able to start from that point and yield values separate from the original (duplicating I/O in every iteration). Anyway, there's no built-in way of forking enumerables so you'd have to implement it yourself. Not worth it. Reify the set and stick to `for` loops.

Comment: Do you really need to check every item `> i` on every element at `i`?

Comment: @madreflection I'm implementing an interface which specifies IEnumerable<T>, this is why I don't *know* the type. But I know with a Lysol degree of confidence (99.99%) that it would be in memory (not a query), so most likely an array or a list.

Comment: In that case, try casting to `IList<T>` (that covers `T[]`, `List<T>`, and more), and fall back using to `ToArray` on it. Then use `for` on that. In your 99.999% case, the cast is a reference conversion so there's zero allocation, and in the 0.001% case, you have to allocate a new array and copy everything. Document that so callers know to be careful.

Comment: `IList<T> subjectSet = input as IList<T> ?? input.ToArray();`

Comment: @Yannici Yes I do, but even if I didn't, like I said, I'm curious. It's a problem that I've come across a couple times. It's been a while since I've done C++ so I might be wrong but I'm pretty sure it would be really easy to do by saving the iterator, I just don't know if it's doable in C#, or even what to google for that matter, hence why I asked the question here

Comment: @madreflection Thanks! I like the idea of using the pattern matching

Comment: No it's impossible. You can't "save" the iterator because that iterator might be arbitrarely complex. In other words, those results don't actually exist anywhere and are generated on the fly. Perhaps what could be done is to write a Linq-style set of extensions to `IList<T>` which also return `IList<T>` and can therefore be indexed. A better understanding of what your enumerable represents would help a lot.

Comment: I haven't encountered Fork used to meaning splitting an enumerable before. A quick search turns up only one specific instance from "[Can I split an IEnumerable into two by a boolean criteria without two queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769199)"

Comment: Does this answer to your question (possible duplicate)? "Why can't IEnumerator's be cloned?" 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807991/why-cant-ienumerators-be-cloned

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730958/how-can-i-retrieve-the-underlying-list-of-an-ienumerable-without-creating-a-new

Comment: @YevhenCherkes yup it does, thanks!